# How to prevent wix from uninstalling old version when installing new version?

Tags: wix

I have a product and the version is 1.3.9. It has a severe bug when uninstall it. I fix the bug and make the product 1.4.0. Then I want to overwrite the 1.3.9 version whitout unintall it. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Minor Upgrade***: Yes, you need a minor upgrade. It upgrades the product in-place and does not trigger uninstall. After that is done you can run the uninstall - now with a corrected uninstall sequence - and you can use major upgrades again the normal way - but you need to migrate yourself out of trouble with a minor upgrade. [**Minor upgrades have many limitations**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130).

***Note***: it is also a problem that when your next version comes along you need to provide a minor upgrade again to migrate users who are still at the problem version. There are various approaches here - such as using the same minor upgrade wrapped in a setup.exe launcher.

***Clunky Version***: You can also make the new version ask for the user to manually uninstall the previous version. Not a good solution, but possible. Then you avoid the need to have to deliver a migratory minor upgrade as part of future launchers?

---

[Maintanence of minor upgrades for broken major upgrade fixing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46935947/129130) (Michael Urman of Installshield)

---

***Various Fixes***: There are [**many hacks and tools you can use to clean this problem out**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876550/wix-custom-action-dialogbox-on-silent-uninstall-of-application/53876981#53876981), none are ideal (do visit that link).