# MsiOpenDatabaseW throws access violation when executed within an msi custom action

Tags: c++, debugging, windows-installer, access-violation

I have a code that modifies a **cached** (not the one being installed) msi installer database which **works fine** when executed within a standalone exe. But when it is run from within an msi Custom Action I get an access violation that is very strange.

```
const auto& msiProductCode = ::GetProductCode(::msiUpgradeCode);
const auto& msiPath = ::GetCachedMSIPath(msiProductCode);

PMSIHANDLE dbHandle{};
const auto res = MsiOpenDatabaseW(msiPath.data(), MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT, &dbHandle); // access violation here within msi castom aciton
```

The exception message:

```
Exception thrown at 0x76246E10 (rpcrt4.dll) in msiexec.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.
```

The call stack:
[image]

What I can't understand is how it even ends up in the `rpcrt4.dll`, since a standalone executable does not have that dependency:

```
Dump of file .\disable_custom_action.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Image has the following dependencies:

    msi.dll
    MSVCP140D.dll
    VCRUNTIME140D.dll
    VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
    ucrtbased.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
```

The dll for the msi custom action, however, has this dependency due to the use of RPC in other
Custom Action functions. `In-Script execution` for this Custom Action is configured to `Immediate Execution`.

1 **What might cause the access violation within when running withinthe msi Custom Action?**
2 Can `MsiOpenDatabaseW` somehow depend on `rpcrt4.dll`?
3 **Can it be caused by a possible inconsistence in C/Cpp Runtime linkage (different CRT versions)?**

---

My initial problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434966/how-to-disable-a-particular-customaction-for-previously-installed-version-during). I though that I figured it out, before the answer revealed the part where I can't call `MsiOpenDatabaseW` during an active installation.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't use `MsiOpenDatabase` from a custom action:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msiopendatabasew)

> Because MsiOpenDatabase initiates database access, it cannot be used with a running installation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70440925/9363996 this answer suggested an approcah to ammend a Custom Action (though didn't mention if I could run it during the installation).   My initial problem is described in the question down the link: how can I amend a Custom Action condition of a cached msi *during* an upgrade installation?

Comment: what if I had it called within a subprocess started by a Custom Action?

Comment: I think it has to be clarified whether you can't use `MsiOpenDatabase` "with a running installation" at all or just can't open a database of *the msi package being installed*. Because my executable that modifies the cached msi database works fine during an active installation (windows installer running in parallel + exe modifies the db).

Comment: I agree the documentation is vague but I wouldn't count on being able to open *any* database from a custom action.

Comment: Running an executable in a Custom Action that modifies the cached database *worked* in my case. It *does not* work when running a dll function that opens a database.